# dnf crashes with segmentation fault

Tags: crash, segmentation-fault, fedora-25, dnf

Fedora 4.10.8-200.fc25.i686+PAE

dnf is crashing with 'segmentation fault (core dumped)'.

I have tried to run 'dnf clean all' without success.

When running 'dnf upgrade', this is logged in dnf.log:

```
Apr 30 20:17:21 INFO --- logging initialized ---
Apr 30 20:17:21 DDEBUG timer: config: 7 ms
Apr 30 20:17:21 DEBUG cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
Apr 30 20:17:21 DEBUG Loaded plugins: reposync, Query, noroot, needs-restarting, protected_packages, builddep, playground, config-manager, copr, download, system-upgrade, debuginfo-install, generate_completion_cache
Apr 30 20:17:21 DEBUG DNF version: 1.1.10
Apr 30 20:17:21 DDEBUG Command: dnf upgrade
Apr 30 20:17:21 DDEBUG Installroot: /
Apr 30 20:17:21 DDEBUG Releasever: 25
Apr 30 20:17:21 DDEBUG Base command: upgrade
Apr 30 20:17:21 DDEBUG Extra commands: []
Apr 30 20:17:51 DDEBUG repo: downloading from remote: updates, _Handle: metalnk: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f25&arch=i386, mlist: None, urls [].
```

This is logged in 'messages':

```
Apr 30 20:17:51 emil2 audit: ANOM_ABEND auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 ses=10 pid=23817 comm="dnf" exe="/usr/libexec/system-python" sig=11
Apr 30 20:17:51 emil2 kernel: dnf[23817]: segfault at 24 ip b64a9c81 sp bfe10cc0 error 4 in libssl3.so[b6496000+49000]
Apr 30 20:17:51 emil2 abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 23817 (system-python) of user 0 killed by SIGSEGV - dumping core
Apr 30 20:17:52 emil2 abrt-server: Deleting problem directory ccpp-2017-04-30-20:17:51-23817 (dup of ccpp-2017-04-28-22:02:01-6627)
Apr 30 20:17:52 emil2 dbus-daemon[721]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.problems' requested by ':1.699' (uid=0 pid=23827 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/abrt-action-notify -d /v") (using servicehelper)
Apr 30 20:17:52 emil2 dbus-daemon[721]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
```

What can I do to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 4):

Got the same problem after upgrade

```
libdb-5.3.28-16 to libdb-5.3.28-24
libdb-utils-5.3.28-16 to libdb-utils-5.3.28-24
```

Rebuild the rpm db fixed it

```
  % rm /var/lib/rpm/__db*
  % rpm --rebuilddb
```

Comment: Thank you RSG for taking the time to write this. Unfortunately do I already have libdb-5.3.28-16.fc25.i686 and libdb-utils-5.3.28-16.fc25.i686.

I have also tried to first delete the files /var/lib/rpm/__db* and then rebuild. Without success. db_verify shows no errors.

Comment: just `rpm --rebuilddb` solved the dnf segfault problem for me. no rollback or manual removal of dbfiles needed in my case.

Comment: Failure could also come from a plugin.  Re-run with `-v` and you can figure out which plugin as a first step.  Can also disable that plugin with `--disableplugin=<PLUGIN>`, in my case it was `generate_completion_cache`.  But if that's the case you will probably need to run additional debugging see what specifically it hates.

Answer (score 0):

> I recently got the same problem and for me the solution was to rebuild
> the rpm db as mentioned by RSG in the answer above with slight
> modification and after that I had to remove all the dnf cache to make
> it work.

**To remove the old rpm db.**

```bash
cd /var/lib/rpm
rm -rf * # make sure you have only db files there.
```

**To rebuild the rpm db.**

```bash
rpm --rebuilddb -v # make sure to add -v to get more details, it will help you to solve errors during the rebuild. As suggested by nhed's comment.
```

**The to remove the cache.**

```bash
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/dnf
```

After removing the entire `dnf` directory from the cache directory.

Finally, The problem was solved.

*You can learn more about what exactly is a segmentation error, Here. [link](https://dzone.com/articles/detecting-and-solving-segmentation-faults-in-linux)
In short it's a error occurred due to failed attempt of accessing the os's memory.*